# Get route to an action from outside the method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, integration-testing, url-routing

Similar to [Get the full route to current action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511568/get-the-full-route-to-current-action), but I want to get the route from outside of the controller method.

```
  [ApiController]
  public class TestController : ControllerBase {

    public IActionResult OkTest() {
      return Ok(true);
    }
  }
```

Then a test class:

```
public class TestControllerTests {

    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public TestControllerTests() {
      _client = TestSetup.GetTestClient();
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task OkTest() {
      var path = GetPathHere(); // should return "/api/test/oktest". But what is the call?
      var response = await _client.GetAsync(path);
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: See if it fits your needs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977352/manually-pass-a-url-through-the-modelbinder-to-obtain-the-routedata-parameters?rq=1

Comment: One idea is to use applications designed to automate API testing.... Like SoapUI.

Comment: As an option you can have a proxy generator and use the generated proxy. As another option you can have some metadata about APIs and and get the URL from metadata. As another option you can rely on some conventions.

Comment: Using swagger you should be able to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Take a look at [Get started with NSwag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) or [Get started with Swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) or [OpenAPI tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/microsoft.dotnet-openapi?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach seems to provide desired result. But this basically instantiates the whole application in order to get to the configured services:

```
    private string GetPathHere(string actionName)
    {
        var host = Program.CreateWebHostBuilder(new string[] { }).Build();
        host.Start();
        IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider provider = (host.Services as ServiceProvider).GetService<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>();
        return provider.ActionDescriptors.Items.First(i => (i as ControllerActionDescriptor)?.ActionName == actionName).AttributeRouteInfo.Template;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void OkTestShouldBeFine()
    {
        var path = GetPathHere(nameof(ValuesController.OkTest)); // "api/Values" in my case
    }
```

However I suspect more complex cases will require a bit more massaging.